# How to make update mysql table row from form: Laravel 5.8

Tags: mysql, laravel, forms, edit

I am having trouble updating a row on my Laravel project. The form receives all the necessary information perfectly, but once I hit the update button, the information parsed from the form is returned as null

My edit (form) file

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
    <h1 class = "title">Edit Item</h1>

    <form method="post" action="/listings/{{$listing->id}}">

        @method('patch')
        @csrf

        <div>
            <label class="label" for="name">Name of Item</label>
            <div class="control">
                <input required type="text" class="input" name="description" placeholder="Name of Item"  value="{{$listing->title}}" >
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            {!! Form::select('lstatus',$lstatus,null) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
                <button type="submit" class="button is-link">Update</button>
            </div>
        </div>


    </form>
```

My controller:

```
    public function edit(listing $listing, lstatus $lstatus)
    {
        $listing = $listing::find($listing->id);
        $lstatus = lstatus::pluck('name','id');
        return view('listings.edit', compact('listing','lstatus'));
    }
    public function update(listing $listing, lstatus $lstatus){



    $listing = listing::find($listing->id);

    $listing->listing_status_id = request('lstatus');
    $listing->title=\request('description');

    return back();

    }
```

When I hit the submit button on the form, nothing happens. Nothing changes in the database and I get no error.

The expected result would be for the values to update.

Comment: you must save = `$listin->save();`

Comment: I feel like an idiot for not seeing that. Thank you a bunch! Is there a better way to pass all the parameters at once?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you could use the `update()` method passing all the inputs from the request with the `all()` method as a parameter, this will save all the attributes you send it in your request automatically:

```
$listing = $listing::find($listing->id);
$listing->update($listing->all());
```

[all method:](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests)

> You may also retrieve all of the input data as an array using the all method:

[update method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#updates):

> The update method expects an array of column and value pairs representing the columns that should be updated.

If you don't use the `update()` method, you should use the `save()` method after you make any change:

```
 $listing->listing_status_id = request('lstatus');
 $listing->title=\request('description');
 $listing->save();
```